# Negative scores in the "Review New Users Posts" are shown on two lines

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, review-page

I was looking at the [review page](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/review/late-answers?s=1&pagesize=15&filter=month), and noticed that negative scores are shown on two lines instead of one.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the issue has been resolved.

[image: screenshot]